# How to get history messages from ActiveMQ?

Tags: apache-kafka, activemq-classic

How to get history messages from ActiveMQ like Kafka's consumer group, from beginning?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625848/how-to-see-dequeued-messages-in-activemq/43637109#43637109

Answer (score 3):

No. ActiveMQ does not store messages longer than needed for delivery to be complete. If you need to keep track of history - you should implement something for that purpose. ActiveMQ offers [mirrored queues](http://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html) so that all queues can be wire-taped at once. But actual storage has to be made by hand.

From own experience - it's easy to implement archiving to a database, but if you want to make some decent search queries, handle replay of older messages etc - it takes some thought